# how to get the items changed in spinner android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to change the value of the second spinner when the value of the first spinner is changed I tried the solutions but did not get an exact solution so anyone have a solution for that so please suggest or any question then please ask

```
ArrayAdapter<String> deptArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Province));
        deptArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerProvinceEyeTest.setAdapter(deptArrayAdapter);
        deptArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i am setting the values in spinner using given code and i have run this code in onStart() method and trying to get the changed value by spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: can you please edit this post with code of both of your spinners, right now it is only for a single spinner, it will help others to find a solution to your problem much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set a `OnItemSelectedListener()` first.

   ```
   spinnerProvinceEyeTest.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
       {
           String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); //this is your selected item

       }
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
       {

       }           
   });
   ```
2. In `onItemSelected()` of above Listener, place your condition and set resource for second `Spinner` as:

   ```
   If(selectedItem == "YourText"){
       //Here, you're initalizing the second `Spinner`
       ArrayAdapter<String> secondArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.YourList));
       secondArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       secondSpinner.setAdapter(secondArrayAdapter);
   }
   else{
       //Use any other list with arrayAdapter in case of other item selected.
       //Use can use If-else-if or Switch to select different resource for different item of first spinner
   }
   ```

Reference - [Official Documentations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner).